# Does tensor product for modules imply the existence of $\otimes: M \times N \rightarrow M \otimes N?$

Tags: category-theory, tensor-products

So in my lecture notes it says that if the functor $F_{M, N}$ from the category of abelian groups to the category of sets is representable by some object $A$ then we call $A = M \otimes N.$ However, it seems to also say that this also comes with a map $\otimes: M \times N \rightarrow M \otimes N.$ Why is this true? For a function to be representable we need an isomorphism from $Bil_R(M \times N, A)$ to $Bil_R(M \otimes N, A)$ for all $A.$ Why does that imply we have this intermediate function $\otimes$ such that for any $f \in Bil_R(M \otimes N, A)$ we have a bijection expressed by $f \mapsto f \circ \otimes.$

Comment: What is $F_{M,N}$? Presumably, $F_{M,N}=Bil_R(M\times N, -)$(?) Also, I either don't know what you mean by $Bil_R$, or I think you are using it incorrectly.

Comment: $F_{M, N}$ is the functor that sends an abelian group $G$ to $Bil_R(M \times N, G)$ the set of $R-$bilinear maps.

Comment: Wouldn't $R$-bilinear maps require $G$ to have the structure of an $R$-module? Maybe you wanted $\mathbb{Z}$-bilinear maps(?)

Answer (score 1):

One way of expressing the universal property of the tensor product is via the following representation: $\mathbf{Mod}_R(M\otimes N,-)\cong \text{Bilin}_R(M,N;-)$ where $\text{Bilin}_R(M,N;S)$ is the set of bilinear functions from $M$ and $N$ into $S$ (with post-composition as its functorial action), and $\mathbf{Mod}_R$ is the hom-functor of the category of $R$-modules, i.e. $\mathbf{Mod}_R(M,N)$ is the set of module homomorphisms (i.e. $R$-linear maps) from $M$ to $N$. (You actually seem to be talking about $\mathbf{Ab}(U(M\otimes N), -)\cong\text{Bilin}_\mathbb{Z}(UM, UN; -)$ where $U : \mathbf{Mod}_R\to\mathbf{Ab}$ is the functor which forgets the scalar multiplication of the $R$-module. This doesn't really change the reasoning below.)

In general, representability is a natural isomorphism $F\cong\mathcal{C}(X,-)$ where $F : \mathcal{C}\to\mathbf{Set}$. In this particular case, $F=\text{Bilin}_R(M,N;-)$, $X=M\otimes N$, and $\mathcal{C}=\mathbf{Mod}_R$. For any representation there is the universal element which is the image of $id_X\in\mathcal{C}(X,X)$. In this case, we get a bilinear function $M\times N \to M\otimes N$, i.e. an element of $\text{Bilin}_R(M,N;M\otimes N)$. In the general case, let $\eta$ be the universal element of $FX$. Via naturality, we can show that for every object $Y$ of $\mathcal{C}$, every element of $FY$ can be written as $Ff\circ \eta$ where $f \in \mathcal{C}(X,Y)$. Naturality is necessary for this; it is not enough simply to have a bijection $FY\cong\mathcal{C}(X,Y)$ for each $Y$. Returning to the specific case, representability of $\text{Bilin}_R(M,N;-)$ means that for every $R$-module $S$, every $R$-bilinear function $h : M\times N \to S$ can be written as the $R$-bilinear function $\eta : M\times N \to M\otimes N$ followed by an $R$-*linear* function $\overline h : M\otimes N \to S$, i.e. $\overline h\in\mathbf{Mod}_R(M\otimes N, S)$. Or in more  traditional notation, for every $R$-bilinear function $h$, $h(m,n) = \overline h(m\otimes n)$ for a unique $R$-linear function $\overline h$ where $m\otimes n$ stands for $\eta(m,n)$. (Uniqueness comes from the isomorphism/bijection aspect. You should spell this out in the general case.)